# CakePHP login method read session if exists for redirect

Tags: php, cakephp

I have disabled `autoRedirect` so I can do some extra jazz in the login method of my users controller and use a Session to send them back to where they came from.

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Users';

    var $components = array('Session');

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();

        $this->Auth->allow(array('login','logout','admin_logout','admin_login')); 

        $this->Session->write('back_to', $this->referer());
    }

    /**
     * Log in
     */

    function admin_login ()
    {
        $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Log in &ndash; Admin &mdash;');

        if(!(empty($this->data)) && $this->Auth->user())
        {   

            $back_to = $this->Session->read('back_to');

            if($back_to)
            {
                $this->redirect($back_to, null, true);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(), null, true);
            }
        }

        if($this->Auth->user())
        {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(), null, true);
        }

    }
```

So the idea is that if a user has the session (99.% of the time) then on submit of form it will send the user TO the previous page, if not then send to the default loginRedirect.

**NOTE: by setting `autoRedirect` to false, CakePHP no longer uses the `Auth.Redirect` session! So the value stored there is not used by the app anymore and is intentional!**

The problem I am having is that my app is ALWAYS sending the user to the dashboard because of the function below 'This one' comment in the code above. If I remove that function then the user is just sent BACK to the login form all the time BUT they will be logged in!

Can anyone help?

Thanks

UPDATE: here is my appcontroller code:

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    var $components = array('Auth','Session');

        public function beforeFilter()
        {

            parent::beforeFilter();

            $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';

            $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;

            $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login','admin'=>true
            );

            $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('admin'=>true,'controller' => 'dashboard', 'action' => 'index');

            $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('admin'=>false,'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display','home');
        }

    function isAuthorized()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: According to this page: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1270/loginRedirect you should be using the default redirect mechanism to do what you want. Unless what you want is to redirect even if the last does not require login...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not existing after redirection. Try changing your redirection signature to:

```
$this->redirect( $back_to, null, true );
```

The 2nd argument is a status code and the third is whether to stop processing the current action. This should prevent you from dropping down to the last redirection which I'm guessing is the one being executed.

Given our long comment "discussion" below, try tweaking your `admin_login()` method like this:

```
if(!(empty($this->data)) && $this->Auth->user()) {
  $back_to = $this->Session->read('back_to');

  if($back_to) {
    $this->redirect($back_to, null, true);
  }
  else {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(), null, true);
  }
}
else {
  # Only write back_to when you arrive at the login page without data
  $this->Session->write('back_to', $this->referer());
}
```

Comment: The user is still not sent to the correct location though. They're either sent to the dashboard or back to the login form and NOT to the location that is stored in the session `back_to`.

Comment: My first question would be are you sure that `back_to` is in the session? There aren't many details, but the code seems to be dropping through to your `else` condition if the login was successful.

Comment: Also, can you update your code in the original question to include any changes you've made (I'm assuming that you've at least made the change to exit after redirection). Also is the user directed to a dedicated login page (e.g. `/users/login`) from which they authenticate?

Comment: Added updated code to OP. Yes I have added the exit after redirection. And the user is just redirected to a login page with prefix of admin. Cheers

Comment: It seems to me that you're updating that session variable with every single request to the `UsersController`. Wouldn't you only want to do that if the user arrives at the login screen without any data? That way you're only setting the `back_to` value when it matters. Am I reading that wrong?

Comment: If you think that is what is causing the problem could you show me how to fix it? I also think my login method is a bit ropey as it has two conditional checks for the the user so perhaps that is also causing problems. Cheers

Comment: Any updates on this? Sorry to keep asking but really want to get this working as it's holding up a project :P cheers

Comment: Try removing `$this->Session->write('back_to', $this->referer());` from `beforeFilter()`. Instead, update your `admin_login()` method  with the removed code in an `else` block of the test for the existence of data.

Comment: Works great :) I've added my full code as an answer too as I've modified it to deal with authentication redirects.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> function login (){
>   if(!empty($this->data) && !$this->Auth->user()){
>     $this->Session->write('back_to', $this->referer());
>   }
> ```

remove that Session->write in your beforeFilter. And you don't need `$this->Auth->allow(array('login','logout'));`

Comment: Still doesn't work and still sends the user to the dashboard. Also the session is never updated with the new value until the form submits hence it being in the beforefilter.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(!(empty($this->data)) && $this->Auth->user())
    {
        $back_to = $this->Session->read('back_to');

        $auth_redirect = $this->Session->read('Auth.redirect');

        if($auth_redirect)
        {
            $this->redirect($auth_redirect, null, true);
        }
        else if($back_to)
        {
            $this->redirect($back_to, null, true);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(), null, true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->Session->write('back_to', $this->referer());
    }
```